# For loop that outputs a unique dataframe after each iteration

Tags: r, for-loop

I know there must be a simple way in R to iterate this process in a For loop, but I am pretty new at writing loops.  Here is the process that I would like to accomplish with a loop

```
sfus1a<-ddply(sfus,.(Phylum),nrow);sfus1a[1,1]
sfus1b<-subset(sfus,sfus$Phylum==sfus1a[1,1])
sfus1<-ddply(sfus1b,.(Genus),nrow);sfus1

sfus1a<-ddply(sfus,.(Phylum),nrow);sfus1a[2,1]
sfus1b<-subset(sfus,sfus$Phylum==sfus1a[2,1])
sfus2<-ddply(sfus1b,.(Genus),nrow);sfus2

sfus1a<-ddply(sfus,.(Phylum),nrow);sfus1a[3,1]
sfus1b<-subset(sfus,sfus$Phylum==sfus1a[3,1])
sfus3<-ddply(sfus1b,.(Genus),nrow);sfus3

sfus1a<-ddply(sfus,.(Phylum),nrow);sfus1a[4,1]
sfus1b<-subset(sfus,sfus$Phylum==sfus1a[4,1])
sfus4<-ddply(sfus1b,.(Genus),nrow);sfus4
```

so the output should be four dataframes sfus1, sfus2, sfus3, and sfus4

The following loop that I attempted to write does not work

```
for(i in 1:4){
  sfus1a<-ddply(sfus,.(Phylum),nrow);sfus1a[i,1]
  sfus1b<-subset(sfus,sfus$Phylum==sfus1a[i,1])
  sfusi<-ddply(sfus1b,.(Genus),nrow);sfusi
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a list first otherwise the `for` loop will overwrite the variable each iteration

```
# pre-allocate lists
sfus1a <- vector(mode = "list", length = nrow(sfus))
sfus1b <- vector(mode = "list", length = nrow(sfus))
sfusi <- vector(mode = "list", length = nrow(sfus))

for(i in 1:4){
  sfus1a[i] <- ddply(sfus, .(Phylum), nrow)
  sfus1b[i] <- subset(sfus, sfus$Phylum == sfus1a[i, 1])
  sfusi[i] <- ddply(sfus1b, .(Genus), nrow)
}
```

This might need some slight tweaking as there wasn't a sample data set to test against